# How to register form for WM_DEVICECHANGE message in windows mobile

Tags: c#, c++, .net-3.5, windows-mobile

I am using C# .NET 3.5 Compact Framework to write code.. please can any one tell me how do i register a form for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`  and how to handle that message in `WindowProc`..

if I do this I get intimation of device hardware change.. I m not getting how to write please tell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The key is to create a class deriving from NativeWindow, give this the handle of your form to call AssignHandle with, and override the WndProc function (allowing you to do what you want with WM_DEVICECHANGE).

See the example on this MSDN page for more details: [Overriding the NativeWindow.WndProc Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.wndproc(VS.85).aspx)

[EDIT] Not completely sure if the NativeWindow class is available in the compactFramework yet. If not, Alex Yakhnin has the class and a sample application of how to catch messages available  [here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink.aspx?guid=eacd2a5f-a7fb-4bce-9336-f974ea2d2e29). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually WM_DEVICECHANGE is unlikely to be what you want.  You probably want to hook into Windows CE's device notification queue by calling [RequestDeviceNotifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx) and passing to it a handle to a queue created with [CreateMsgQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885180.aspx).

If you don't feel like writing all of this P/Invoke code, as usual the Smart Device Framework already has it already done and in a more logical object model.