# Detect USB - Insert/Remove - VB.NET on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, usb-drive

I'm becoming mad trying to figure out how to resolve this task. My goal is pretty easy, copy a file on the USB stick every time that it is inserted and then release the USB stick turning off the LED. What is the best way to solve it?

1) I found this article

http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/13/windows-ce-monitoring-for-disk-insertion-to-add-support-for.aspx

or

http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/13/windows-ce-monitoring-for-disk-insertion-to-add-support-for.aspx

but I can't translate it on VB.NET project.

2) Then I read that is enough to use **RequestDeviceNotifications** for block devices. But How can I do that in VB.NET?

I would like to avoid OpenNetCF if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to "use OpenNETCF" I assume that you don't want to use any libraries or capabilities not built in to the CF.  We'll skip the argument of that silliness and the "value of your time" discussion and take that as a requirement.

What you need to do is:

1. Use P/Invoke to call [CreateMsgQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885180.aspx).  That's going to give you back a Handle.  You'll probably want to do CloseMsgQueue as well for completeness
2. P/Invoke [RequestDeviceNotifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx) and pass it the handle returned from #1 above along with the [DEVCLASS GUID value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447465.aspx) for the device notifications you want - probably STORE_MOUNT_GUID.  Again, adding StopDeviceNotifications for completeness is a good idea.
3. At that point you'll get a message on the queue whenever a insert or remove happens.  You then call [ReadMsgQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886793) to get the [DEVDETAIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898286.aspx) data in the message.
4. Parse the DEVDETAIL and look at the `fAttached` member.

Comment: I'm sure that OpenNETCF is a great add-on for the compact framework but I'm developing an application for industrial purpose that should run 24/7 without issues and I have already many libraries outside CF. You know that every X line of codes you have Y errors and I'm trying to avoid adding a lot of other stuff if possible...and this looked to me a very basic functionality and it seems "stupid?" to me that CF doesn't provide an easy way to do it.

Comment: There are a load of things the CF doesn't provide the capability for (and that was the primary driver for creating the SDF).  The above steps will get you the notifications you're after - and it's really the only way to do it.  It's just not as straightforward as you'd probably hoped.

Comment: Yes, you right. But...finally I give up to OpenNetCF. It seems that limit of CF are so deep and I can't take all this time to workaround all these features...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It'd take me a while to write that for you, so you'll need to do this on your own.

Start writing the project, find P/Invoke routines for the calls you need (like `FindFirstFile` and `CreateProcess`). On SO, have a look at [Storage Card Problem In windows mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464510) and [How to register form for WM_DEVICECHANGE message in windows mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436979).

You are only going to be dead in the water if you can not find a particular call that you can't make.

As you work through your project, post (or search for) the actual problems you run into.

Otherwise, it sounds like you are asking someone to write the project and hand it to you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not asking someone to write code for me, just searching for a tutorial and/or snippet of code to do this stuff!